# Boost Matrix Order of Operations

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I have overloaded the additions and multiplication operators.
If I have a program like this:

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
typedef boost::numeric::ublas ublas;

int main()
{
   ublas::matrix<double> A(10,10,5);
   double c1 = 10;
   double c2 = 1;

   A = (A*c1) + c2; // something like this wouldn't work.
   // But if i change it to
   A = A*c1;
   A = A+c2;
   // this will work.
   return 0;
}
```

how do I make it so that `A = A*c2+c1;` or `A = (A*c2)+c1` works?

Comment: use parenthesis....`A = (A * c2) + c1`.  BTW, the statement above are not the same...you switched the `c1` and `c2` somewhere.

Comment: `A = (A * c1) + ((A * c1) + c2)`

Comment: can someone explain why first version is not supposed to work?

Comment: `A = A*c2+c1;// something like this wouldn't work.` -- [really](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1at2Ai$2)?  Maybe your problem involves `const` keywords and temporaries?

Comment: If the second version does what he wants, then the first version can't possibly work.  He's simply stating his desired formula incorrectly.

Comment: Carey, I wanted the first statement A = (A*c1)+c2. Adding parentheses doesn't work.

Comment: As always: What's the error message?

Comment: The problem is that you can't add a matrix and a scalar. A=A+c2 doesn't work either. If you want to add c2 to every component you would need to do something like [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/6P0Tw$1).

Comment: Error 95 error C2088: '+' : illegal for class 
Error 93 error C2676: binary '+' : 'boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_binary_scalar1<E1,E2,F>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator